# I can't filter or search

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I have a big problem and I passed the lasts 2 hours on it.

I have this DataTabe :

```
const tableauAjoutCandidat = $("#tableauAjoutCandidats").DataTable({
    select: "multi",
    searching: false,
    columns: [
        {
            name: "nomPrenom",
            title: "NOM Prénom",
            data: "nom"
        },
        {
            name: "dateNaissance",
            title: "Date de naissance",
            data: "datenaissance",
            render: function(data) {
                return moment(data, 'YYYY-MM-DD').format('DD/MM/YYYY');
            }
        },
        {
            name: "besoins",
            title: "Besoins",
            data: "besoins"
        },
        {
            name: "epr",
            title: "EPR",
            data: "epr",
            render: function(data) {
                if (data == false) {
                    return '<input class="checkboxEPR" type="checkbox" value="" />';
                } else {
                    return '<input class="checkboxEPR" type="checkbox" value="" checked />';
                }
            }
        },
        {
            name: "demande",
            title: "Demande",
            data: 'demande'
        }
    ],
    ajax: {
        url: Routing.generate("exercicepratique_candidats_potentiels", {epId: epId}),
        dataSrc: 'candidats'
    },
    columnDefs: [
        { targets: 1, "type": "date-euro" },
    ]
});
```

In this DataTabla, the last column, "Demande", contain `TRUE` or `FALSE` and I want to filter to just see the lines with `TRUE` when a checkbox is unchecked and to see all the lines when its checked.

So I have tried multiple things.
First I try to make it with a filter, like this :

```
tableauAjoutCandidat.column('demande:name').data().filter(function (value, index) {
    const checked = $('#filtreDemandeConvocationEP').is(':checked');
    if (!checked && value != true) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
});

$('#filtreDemandeConvocationEP').on('change', function() {
    tableauAjoutCandidat.draw();
)};
```

but it doesn't work at all...

Then I try to make it with a search, like this :

```
$('#filtreDemandeConvocationEP').on('change', function() {
    const checked = $('#filtreDemandeConvocationEP').is(':checked');
    if (!checked) {
        tableauAjoutCandidat.column('demande:name').search('true').draw();
    } else {
        tableauAjoutCandidat.column('demande:name').draw();
    }
});
```

but with the same result...

So now I don't know what to try... I hope someone can help me.
Thanks !

PS: Sorry for my english, as you can see it's not my native language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the answer !

I have an other DataTable on my page and a filter on it. Its this filter that was in conflict with my search option on my 2nd DataTable.
So I put an `if` in my filter to make it work just on the DataTable I want.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried enabling searching? I see you have set searching = false.

According to their docs:
Note that if you wish to use the search abilities of DataTables this must remain **true**

https://datatables.net/reference/option/searching

```
const tableauAjoutCandidat = $("#tableauAjoutCandidats").DataTable({
    select: "multi",
    searching: true,
    columns: [
        {
            name: "nomPrenom",
            title: "NOM Prénom",
            data: "nom"
        },
        {
            name: "dateNaissance",
            title: "Date de naissance",
            data: "datenaissance",
            render: function(data) {
                return moment(data, 'YYYY-MM-DD').format('DD/MM/YYYY');
            }
        },
        {
            name: "besoins",
            title: "Besoins",
            data: "besoins"
        },
        {
            name: "epr",
            title: "EPR",
            data: "epr",
            render: function(data) {
                if (data == false) {
                    return '<input class="checkboxEPR" type="checkbox" value="" />';
                } else {
                    return '<input class="checkboxEPR" type="checkbox" value="" checked />';
                }
            }
        },
        {
            name: "demande",
            title: "Demande",
            data: 'demande'
        }
    ],
    ajax: {
        url: Routing.generate("exercicepratique_candidats_potentiels", {epId: epId}),
        dataSrc: 'candidats'
    },
    columnDefs: [
        { targets: 1, "type": "date-euro" },
    ]
});
```

Comment: Yes, and when I do that my DataTable appears empty, like if there is already a search word.